# Is it safe to use Vue.js for embedded content?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-applications, vuejs2, reactive-programming

I'm converting an existing web app to Vue, but there are a few contingencies that give me pause. This web app exists as both standalone content and as embedded content in third party pages. I don't control the third party page, so it's entirely possible that the third party page could use React or Vue, or any other js framework. I know that multiple Vue instances on a page likely won't cause any issues other than possibly naming conflicts.

What I'm worried about is whether mixing React and Vue on a single page is possible. If so, what would be the potential side effects?

Is embedding a Vue app into a third party page simply a bad idea?

Comment: I don't understand how the content could be embedded in any way other than a webview or an iframe, so I'd say it doesn't matter. Actually, I take it back, they could be scraping the page for the raw HTML and displaying it and if that's the case you're SOL.

Comment: The content is requested by the third party on their server, then embedded in the page when rendering.